# Enabling NTLM authentication for the ASP.NET Development Web Server but isnt there in VS 2015 enterprise edition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, claims-based-identity

I am writing a claims-aware app in C# using visual studio 2015 enterprise edition and I am following the tutorial from this link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

I have followed the directions up to figure 1 and VS 2015 doesn't have NTLM authentication. I would like to enable NTLM so I can continue this tutorial but I do not know how else to enable NTLM. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Windows authentication is formally known as NTLM. Windows authentication can be enable within the source code of the web.config file within an MVC project.